# how to redirect a form within turbo_frame?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6.1, hotwire-rails, turbo

I need to add a button that persists the data of the following form but that when pressing it resets the view and stays in it, without redirecting to the index of the controller, I have tried an ajax call but I don't know why it didn't work for me.
How can I give a solution and add the button to save and continue?

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag dom_id(taxonomy) do %>
  <%= form_with(model: [:admin, taxonomy], id: dom_id(taxonomy)) do |form| %>
<div class="box">
  <div class="field is-horizontal">
    <div class="field-body">
      <div class="field">
        <div class="control is-expanded is-relative">
          <%= form.text_field :name, placeholder: true, class: "input mt-5" %>
          <%= form.label :name, class: "label-hidden required" %>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="field is-narrow">
        <div class="control mt-5">
          <%= form.submit nil, class: "button is-primary" %>
          <%= link_to "#{ t '.cancel'}", admin_taxonomies_path, class: "button is-light" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add a target="_top" attribute to the frame: `turbo_frame_tag dom_id(taxonomy), target: :_top`
Otherwise Turbo tries to replace the current frame containing the form.

Answer (score 4):

You can also just add `data-turbo="false"` on your link and the redirection will be working fine.

More info here in the documentation
https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/drive#disabling-turbo-drive-on-specific-links-or-forms